# How to deal with fake accounts without having to take personal details like phone number or email

Tags: user-interface, authentication

This is not a programming question sorry about that. It's more of a design approach.
How to deal with fake accounts without having to take personal details like phone number or email.

Usually websites make sure the user is unique by asking for phone number or email address which is then verified using an OTP or a verify link.

Is there any way one can ensure the users are unique without these details?

Comment: By "fake accounts", do you mean "a single person having multiple accounts"?

Comment: Ya I meant the same person having multiple accounts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that they aren't a robot generating accounts then there is always CAPTCHA.

Usually a phone number or email is useful because almost everyone has them, so they are decent for keeping track of users. They don't really ensure that all users are unique though since people can have multiple accounts.

An alternative option would be to store the matching IP addresses and limit the accounts to one per IP, but if the user has multiple devices then this will also fall through, or if they use a VPN.

It's basically impossible to ensure that all accounts are entirely unique users, but a combination of these can limit the amount of users with multiple accounts.